# Deleting and updating a specific element in a vector<struct>

Tags: c++, search, vector

I would like to ask you about helping me with the following task that I have to solve.

There is a structure together with a vector:

```
struct SPerson {
  string name;
  string address;
  string birthcertificatenumber;
};
std::vector<SPerson> People;
```

Lets say that there are already some records:

1. Name: John, address: street 1, Birth certficate number: 801206/2393
2. Name: Jean, address: street 2, Birth certficate number: 701206/2393
3. Name: Matt, address: street 3, Birth certficate number: 601206/2393
4. Name: Peter, address: street 4, Birth certficate number: 501206/2393
5. Name: Pierre, address: street 5, Birth certficate number: 901206/2393
6. Name: Ian,address: street 6, Birth certficate number: 861206/2393
7. Name: Matrix, address: street 7, Birth certficate number: 781208/2393

---

Now I would like to delete and update a specific record. The first thing I have to do is to find the specific item.
The criteria of searching should be according to:

**name and address**

- DeletePerson( "Jean", "street 2" ));
- UpdateAddressOfPerson("Jean", "street 2", "new street"));

or

**birth certificate number**

- DeletePerson ( "701206/2393" ) );
- UpdateAddressOfPerson("701206/2393", "new street"));

---

**Also Important:**

Lets say that there are thousands and thousands records and I need to do the actions **quicky - non-linearly**.

I can neither use map nor set, it is a requirement of the task that I have to solve.

I would like to mention that it should work insensitevely, so it should ignore the size of letters, for example: John is jOhn is JoHn etc. Street 1 ..sTrEet 1...

---

Can you please show me how to delete the person 4 which is Peter with the address street4. And then please show me how to delete the person with the birth certifikate number 861206/2393.

Thank you so much.

---

Examples that I have now which works, but are slow:

Updating function:

```
bool UpdatePerson(const string & name, const string & address, const string & newaddress)
{
  auto it = find_if(begin(People), end(People), [=] (SPerson const& f) { 
    return (strcasecmp(name.c_str(), f.name.c_str()) == 0) and (strcasecmp(address.c_str(), f.address.c_str()) == 0);        
    });
  bool found = (it != end(People));   
  if (found == true)
  {
    it->address = newaddress;
    return true; 
  }
  return false;
}
```

Deleting function:

```
  bool DeletePerson(const string & name, const string & address)
  {
    auto it = find_if(begin(People), end(People), [=] (SPerson const& f) { 
      return ((strcasecmp(name.c_str(), f.name.c_str()) == 0) and (strcasecmp(address.c_str(), f.address.c_str()) == 0));  
    });
      bool found = (it != end(People)); 
      if (found == true)
      {
      People.erase(it);
      items--; 
      return true;     
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using a database for this. All of your requirements are readily supported in most mainstream databases - including multiple indexes, large volumes of data, and case (in)sensitivity. Note that there also exist database implementations that can be embedded in your application if you don't want to rely on an external database.

Comment: On your sample data vector is sorted by street, is it true?

Comment: Use `std::sort` to keep the vector sorted and use `std::lower_bound` to find elements you want to change/delete. That should give `O(log n)`

Comment: Hash maps are the most basic thing to use here. If it is forbidden to use std::map, then you might want to write your own.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Unfortunatelly I cannot use the database, otherwise I would. I should have the O(log n) yes. I heard about lower bound, but the thing is that I do not know how to apply it for  this case, otherwise I would not write here asking for help :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing enough insert, delete and search operation, I would recomment you to use **Hashmap/Unorderedmap** rather than only vector. We would be able to do those operations in O(1) time complexity.

Check for those examples:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/

Answer (score 0):

This looks good for you?

```
#include <algorithm>
auto it = find(People.begin(), People.end(), <value>);
if (it != People.end())
 //do something with it, erase using it.erase()
```

Comment: Good otherwise, but doesn't fulfill *"I need to do the actions quicky - non-linearly."* and requires the class to be equality comparable which hasn't been shown to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

```
DeletePerson( string& name, string& address)
{

auto iter = std::find_if(People.begin(), People.end(), [&](const SPerson& elem) {
 return (elem.name == name && elem.address == address)
});
if (iter != People.end() )
{
    People.erase(iter); // here you erase it or you can update it if you want
}
}
```

Do the same for the other functions just replace the function arguments with with the right fields from SPerson in the comparaisons at the line that contains the return keyword

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I updated my text, so you can notice this functin there which is slow for thousands of thousands records. It is linear.

Comment: What you can do is look for a search algorithm to implement instead of the find_if function : binary search algorithm for example.

Comment: Sure, I know that :) but I do not know how to implement it for this case, otherwise I would not write here :)

Comment: Look for the c++ implementation